# Why lag compensator is preferred over PI for sinusoidal reference?

Tags: filters, filter-design, linear-systems, control-systems, pid

In [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37307/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lag-compensation-and-pi-control) post, LJSilver mentioned that a PI compensator is not appropriate for a constantly changing reference, such as a sinusoidal waveform. In this scenario, a lag compensator is considered the better choice. Can anyone provide a more detailed explanation of why a PI compensator is not suitable here and why a lag compensator is a better option?